# how to run plot of R into C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, r

How do I execute a R command in C, without using R extensions, something like:

```
int main() {

   system("R g<- graph(c(0,1,0,4,0,9,1,7,1,9,2,9,2,3,2,5,3,6,3,9,4,5,4,8,5,8,6,7,6,8,7,8),n=10,dir=FALSE)
    plot(g)")

    return(0)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried that?  Did it fail?  Did you describe the failure to us?

Comment: of course it fails, it just do an example that i want to execute from C

Comment: I just want to plot a graph the same way in R but in C/C++

Comment: Then you may misunderstand what C and C++ are.  Neither language has intrinsic graphics or plotting functionality.  You'll have to specify a platform (Win32, Linux, etc), and pick a graphing library.

Comment: Yes, but to answer your question: http://yusung.blogspot.se/2008/08/link-c-with-r.html  if you want to use exactly R and C.  But you may be better off to use some other graphing library, not R at all.

Comment: But I need the opposite way, I want to use R into C. Ok with extensions R how plot with R_ext/GetX11Image.h, this is mention in "Writing R Extensions" manual

Comment: Have you looked at [Rinside](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RInside/index.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run R using the system() call as you have, but you can't stick R functions on the command line like that.

What you can do is to write the R code to a file and call it with `system("R CMD BATCH foo.R")` - minimally:

```
main(){system("R CMD BATCH test.R");}
```

Now, by default the output graphics from R CMD BATCH go to a PDF file, so you need to open a graphics window and make the script pause if you want to see it.

Of course your test.R file could be written by your C code before it runs it, and you could keep it in a temporary directory or something.

Comment: I don't know what happened, I did it and it continue 0%.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative for `R CMD BATCH` is `Rscript`. I think for problems where C++ and R are not tightly integrated, i.e. there are distinct phases where R and C++ are used, nor large volumes or frequency of data exchange, using system calls can be very simple and robust.

An alternative is to run R and C++ alongside each other and exchange info between them. This can be done using the [RInside pacakge](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html), which is [available on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RInside/index.html).

Comment: Rscript: Simple, yes. Robust no.  Which is why we wrote RInside :)

Comment: What exactly is non robust about Rscript?

Comment: Well, i know there would be more efficient methods, at the moment is enough to use system("R CMD BATCH test.R"), anyway thank you very much for your help!!!